# IBM DB2 9.7, force all connections of a specific database

Tags: db2

I have a DB2 9.7 LUW instance with several databases. I am trying to take backup of a specific database, but Data Studio client reports that there is still an active connection so it fails.

How can I force the database to remove all active connections to that specific database? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in a single command;  you have to list the connections first:

```
LIST APPLICATIONS FOR DB <databasename>
```

Then, use all of the numeric application handles returned by the list above to issue the `FORCE APPLICATION` statement:

```
FORCE APPLICATION (1, 2, 3, 4, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to take an OFFLINE backup. You can use `db2 FORCE APPLICATION ALL`. As listed in [the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001951.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F3-6-2-4-37):

```
ALL - All applications will be disconnected from the database server.
```

Though before you take the force route - I suggest taking a look at `QUIESCE` instead or properly stopping the application. Your backup process would look something like this:

```
# Stop your application

su - db2inst1 # Or whatever instance you have
timestamp=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M)
mkdir backup-mydb-$timestamp

# Connect to your database and check existing connections
db2 CONNECT TO MYDB;
db2 list applications for database MYDB show detail

# QUISCE the database
db2 QUIESCE DATABASE IMMEDIATE FORCE CONNECTIONS;
db2 CONNECT RESET

# Perform the backup
db2 BACKUP DATABASE MYDB TO "/home/db2i2/backup-mydb-$timestamp" WITH 2 BUFFERS BUFFER 1024 PARALLELISM 1 WITHOUT PROMPTING;

# UNQUISCE the database
db2 CONNECT TO MYDB
db2 UNQUIESCE DATABASE;
db2 CONNECT RESET;

# Test the backup
db2ckbkp -h backup-mydb-$timestamp/*

# Start your application
```

You can also use `db2top` to monitor database connections and identify what applications you need to stop.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following steps, and it works.

```
db2 connect to TFBDW
db2 list application for database TFBDW
db2 QUIESCE DATABASE IMMEDIATE FORCE CONNECTIONS;
db2 "force application (39)"
db2 CONNECT RESET
db2 backup database TFBDW_U to "/tmp/dbbackup/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it to be an **OFFLINE** backup, this can be done by either **DEACTIVATE**'ing the database or by **QUISCE**'ing the database.

For **DEACTIVATE**'ing the database, follow the below steps:-

- Confirm applications are down using **LIST APPLICATIONS FOR

  `DB_NAME`** , and if found force them off using **FORCE APPLICATIONS
  ALL**
- Deactivate the database using **DEACTIVATE DB `DB_NAME`**

For **QUISCE**'ing the database, follow the below steps:-

- **CONNECT TO `DBNAME`**
- **QUIESCE DATABASE IMMEDIATE FORCE CONNECTIONS**
- **CONNECT RESET**